# Switch Statement in Groovy

Tags: groovy, switch-statement

I cannot figure out why no matter what the "quotient" is coming into the getNumeral method the only println statement shown is "quotient is 9".  The lows, mids, and highs are the equivalant of the returns to convert Roman Numerals
1000: [M, ?, ?]
100: [C, D, M]
10: [X, L, C]
1: [I, V, X]

The only values of quotient coming in are 1, 2, 3, 4

Here is my first def that calls the getNumeral def:

```
def emitRNValue(int quotient, int divisor) {
Map strokes = [1000:['M', '?', '?'],
    100:['C', 'D', 'M'],
    10:['X', 'L', 'C'],
    1:['I', 'V', 'X']]
// Logic to be provided by you.
// Yes a switch statement works here.
println "INSIDE EMITRNVALUE QUOTIENT IS ${quotient} and divisor: ${divisor}"
String low = ""
String mid = ""
String high = ""

System.out.println("Fetching Keys and corresponding [Multiple] Values n");

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : strokes.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<String> values = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println("Key = " + key);
    System.out.println("Values fetching = " + values);


    low = values[0];
    mid = values[1];
    high = values[2];

    println "Low is " + low
    println "Mid is " + mid
    println "high is " + high + "\n"

    if(divisor == Integer.parseInt(key)) {
        println "divisor and key are same"
        String returnFromGetNumeral = ""
                    returnFromGetNumeral = getNumeral(low, mid, high, quotient)
                    println "RETURN FROM GETNUMERAL################## " + returnFromGetNumeral
    }
    
    

}





strokes.each {entry -> println "************$entry.key: $entry.value"}
strokes.eachWithIndex { key, value, i -> println "$i $key: $value"}
```

}

```
def String getNumeral(String low, String mid, String high, int quotient) {
String romanNumeral = ""
println "QUOTIENT IS INSIDE GETNUMERAL VALUE IS " + quotient;
                switch (quotient) {
                    case quotient <= 3:
                    System.out.println("quotient <= 3")
                      return romanNumeral = low.repeat(quotient);
                    case quotient === 4:
                    System.out.println("quotient = 4")
                      return romanNumeral += low + mid;
                    case quotient <= 8: // quotients 5-8
                    System.out.println("quotient is digits 5-8")
                      return romanNumeral +=  mid + low.repeat(quotient - 5);
                    default: // quotient 9
                    System.out.println("quotient is 9")
                      return  romanNumeral +=low + high
                  }
    
}
```

Comment: There are nice examples of achieving this elsewhere:
https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Encode#Groovy

Answer (score 2):

This is not how the [switch
statement](http://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_switch_case) in Groovy
works.  Usually some constant expression is expected for a case.  So
what is happening there: all your cases become booleans (the result of
`quotient === 4` e.g.) and then the comparsion against the quotient
fails.  Hence the default case being picked.

Allowed cases are (from the docs):

> - Class case values match if the switch value is an instance of the
>   class
> - Regular expression case values match if the toString()
>   representation of the switch value matches the regex
> - Collection case values match if the switch value is contained in the
>   collection. This also includes ranges (since they are Lists)
> - Closure case values match if the calling the closure returns
>   a result which is true according to the Groovy truth

So one way would be using closures:

```
def quotient = 1
switch (quotient) {
    case {it <= 3}:
        println("quotient <= 3")
        break
    case 4:
        println("quotient = 4")
        break
    case {it <= 8}: // quotients 5-8
        println("quotient is digits 5-8")
        break
    default: // quotient 9
        println("quotient is 9")
        break
}
```

Or ranges (e.g. `0..3`).  Which look a bit better:

```
def quotient = 9
switch (quotient) {
    case 0..3:
        println("quotient <= 3")
        break
    case 4:
        println("quotient = 4")
        break
    case 5..8:
        println("quotient is digits 5-8")
        break
    default: // quotient 9
        println("quotient is 9")
        break
}
```

But at this point it might even be more readable to write that out as
regular if/else statements.

Answer (score 1):

I actually refactored the switch into an if/else statement and it worked. Here is the new method utilizing:

```
static emitValue(String low, String mid, String high, int quotient) {
    String romanNumeral = ""

    if (quotient <= 3) {
        return romanNumeral += low.repeat(quotient)
    } else if(quotient == 4) {
        return romanNumeral = low + mid
    } else if(quotient <= 8 ) {
        return romanNumeral += mid + low.repeat(quotient - 5)
    } else {
        return romanNumeral = low + high
    }

}
```